# Passing an image pointer to another program

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers

Is there a way we can create a pointer to an image memory location , pass it to another program and access it from there. We have image container datatypes like Mat using which we read an image

```
cv::Mat m ; 

m = imread("a.jpg") ;
```

can we create pointers to these images and pass it other programs ?

For example i can pass the address of an integer

```
int x = 10 as '&x' to another program by using named pipes for IPC 

write(pipe , &x , sizeof(int));
```

on receivers side

```
read(pipe , &y , sizeof(int));
```

when print y it display 10

will do it for an integer , how can we do it for images.

Comment: Don't tag-spam. This is not C. And what you do with the `int` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `m.data`, or `m.ptr<T>(0)` to get the pointer to the matrix data. It probably doesn't make sense to send to other process, though.

Comment: You can use [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory#Support_on_Unix-like_systems), but the shared memory API is OS dependent.

Answer (score 3):

> can we create pointers to these images and pass it other programs ?

No you can't do that. Pointers are bound to a particular processes virtual memory space and these are meaningless when used in a different process.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use shared memory to do this.  For a POSIX-y system, using `shm_open` and `mmap`, you can create a region of memory that both processes can access.  Note that the address of the region will typically not be the same in both processes however.  Not a windows programmer, but I believe `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` are analogous.  The code example below is an outline of what you might do on linux:

In both process A and B:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

//ensure success by checking fd >= 0!
int fd = shm_open("unique_name", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

//choose length to be some sufficiently large region of memory to
//hold the data structures you want to share.  Both process A and B
//should agree on this.
//ensure success by checking that ptr != 0
void* ptr = mmap(0, length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

//Create your image objects using the memory region you have just created
//using one of the constructors that takes a user-provided data pointer
cv::Mat(rows, cols, type, ptr, step);
```

At this point, anything you do to the object in one process will be reflected in the other.  You need to separately synchronize the two processes (perhaps using a semaphore, message queue or pipe) to ensure consistency of the image content between the two processes.  You can simplify things a bit if process A will always write and process B will always only read the image content.

Hope that helps.